# Is there a tool to protect from or manage LSOs in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, privacy-protection

"Local Shared Objects" are SuperCookies that aren't taken deleted by your browser, have no expiration date, and hold a huge amount of information about you.  They can even turn on your camera or microphone without your permission.  See this [link](http://epic.org/privacy/cookies/flash.html) for more info.

There is a Firefox Addon ([Better Privacy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6623)) but I haven't found anything for Internet Explorer yet.  Does anyone know of a tool for IE that handles these?

Answer (score 3):

[CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com) removes those by default.  See [this thread](http://forum.piriform.com/index.php?showtopic=19641) from their forums for more information.

Comment: This is good to know since I use CCleaner occasionally (now I'll be using it more often).  I'm still hoping there's some way to get IE to auto-delete these upon exit, or something like that.